# Number of Vertices Within a Distance from Start Vertex

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory

I was working on a question on a judge that asked about finding the number of vertices that are within a certain distance from it. This has to be done for all vertices on the graph. The full question specifications can be seen  [here.](https://dmoj.ca/problem/dmopc15c6p6) I have some Python code to solve the program, but it is too slow.

```
import sys, collections
raw_input = sys.stdin.readline
n, m, k = map(int, raw_input().split())
dict1 = collections.defaultdict(set)
ans = {i:[set([i])for j in xrange(k)]for i in xrange(1, n+1)}

for i in xrange(m):
    x, y = map(int, raw_input().split())
    dict1[x].add(y)
    dict1[y].add(x)

for point in dict1:
    ans[point][0].update(dict1[point])

for i in xrange(1, k):
    for point in dict1:
        for neighbour in dict1[point]:
            ans[point][i].update(ans[neighbour][i-1])

for i in xrange(1, n+1):
    print len(ans[i][-1])
```

What my code does is it initially creates a set of points that are direct neighbours of each vertex (distance of 0 to 1). After that, it creates a new set  of neighbours for each vertex from all the previously found neighbours of neighbours (distance of 2). Then it keeps doing this, creating a new set of neighbours and incrementing the distance until the final distance is reached. Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is a plenty of good and fast solutions.

One of them (Not the fastest, but fast enough) is to use BFS algorithm up to distance **K**. Just run bfs, which not adds neighbours to queue when distance exceeds **K**, for all vertexes. **K** is parameter from exercise specification.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [adjacency matrix](https://1stprinciples.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/some-interesting-properties-of-adjacency-matrices/) multiplication. Adjacency matrix is a boolean square matrix `n * n` where `n` is a number of vertices. The value of `adjacency_matrix[i][j]` equals `1` if the edge from `i` to `j` exists and `0` otherwise. If we multiply the adjacency matrix by itself we get the paths of length 2. If we do that again we get the paths of length 3 and so on and so on. In Your case the `K <= 5` so there won't be too much of that multiplication. You can use numpy for that and it will be very fast. So in pseudocode, the solution to Your problem would look like this:

```
adjacency_matrix = build_adjacency_matrix_from_input()
initial_adjacency_matrix = adjacency_matrix
result_matrix = adjacency_matrix
for i = 2 to K:
    adjacency_matrix = adjacency_matrix * initial_adjacency_matrix
    result_matrix = result_matrix + adjacency_matrix
for each row of result_matrix print how many values higher then 0 are in it
```

Comment: Would the adjacency matrix have values greater than 1 after multiplication? And if it does, what happens with those values?

Comment: In the first example, some values were 2 or 3 after multiplication. Are those somehow part of the answer?

Comment: Oh You are right, I'm sorry. Apparently those are the numbers of the different paths. In your case it doesn't matter though, You just have to check if there is number higher then zero. Sorry for my mistake, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Do you know how to quickly square the matrix?

Comment: Use [numpy.dot](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html). It's probably the best method.

Comment: Any non numpy solutions? External libraries can't be used on the judge.

Comment: Oh, thats bad. You would have to implement it by yourself then. But I'm not sure if it's a good solution in that case...

Answer (score 0):

You want paths of length <=K. In this case, BFS can be used to find paths of certain length easily. Or if your graphs uses adjacency matrix representation, then matrix multiplication can also be used for these purposes.

If using BFS:
 This is equivalent to performing level-by-level traversal starting from a given source vertex. Here is the pseudo code that can compute all the vertices that are at distance K from a given source vertex:

```
Start: Let s be your source vertex and K represent max path length required

Create two Queues Q1 and Q2 and insert source vertex s into Q1
Let queueTobeEmptied = Q1 // represents the queue that is to be emptied
Let queueTobeFilled = Q2  // represents the queue that is used for inserting new elements discovered
Let Result be a vector of vertices: initialize it to be empty
Note: source vertex s is at level 0, push it to Result vector if that is also required

for(current_level=1; current_level<=K; current_level++) {
    while(queueTobeEmptied is not empty) {
        remove the vertex from queueTobeEmptied and call it as u
        for_each adjacent vertex 'v' of u {
            if v is not already visited {
                mark v as visited
                insert v into the queueTobeFilled     
                push v to Result                       
            }
        }
    }
    swap the queues now for next iteration of for loop: swap(queueTobeEmptied, queueTobeFilled)
}

Empty Q1 and Q2

End: Result is the vector that contains all the vertices of length <= K
```